# Update online database using a php session in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, session

I need for one of my apps to update a database on my server (likes, comments, etc...) and I thought that the only way to disabilitate bots to update it constantly is through making the user create an account and via java ask for a php script on the server side to update the records, but I don't know how to get the app to understand if a user is logged in or not...

Do you have any ideas that could help me? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In your user table add two extra column device id and token. when a
user is logged in first time generate a random token and send it to
the app and update your database.In app store  that token in
persistence. every time when app starts send that token to server if
token matches with db token that means u r logged in, else not.for
logout send null or zero to server. Try with this.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I thought of that, but you helped me figure everything out well, nice answer